# Defining fallback fonts for entire Unicode ranges

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, unicode, newunicodechar

Is it possible to automatically define fallbackfonts for specific Unicode ranges?

I know there are packages to do this such as `xeCJK` for CJK fonts as in
[this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53599/standard-cjk-fonts-for-latex) answer

But that's limited to those fonts.  I'm particularly interested in Bengali, but maybe there's a more general way.

I know from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224584/define-fallback-font-for-specific-unicode-characters-in-lualatex/224585#224585) question that I can define specific unicode fallback characters.
I've used this for IPA characters, for example.
I could, of course, use the same mechanism and enter each of the (fortunately only 128) Bengali characters as fallback characters.
But it would be neat to have a simpler way of doing this, like specifying
for the range of code points A to B to use font X
for the range of code points C to D to use font Y and so on.

So for example, the Unicode range for Bengali script is from U+0980 to U+09FF (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_(Unicode_block)))
so if there was a way to specify:

- for unicode range U+0980 to U+09FF  use a Bengali font,
- for U+0250 to U+02AF an IPA compatible font

and so on.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
\documentclass{article}

% The standard way of typing Bengali text within a document
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali, Scale=MatchLowercase]{Bangla MN}

% Defining individual fallback characters
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newfontfamily{\fallbackfont}{Junicode}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfallback}{\fallbackfont}
\newcommand{\fallbackchar}[2][\textfallback]{%
    \newunicodechar{#2}{#1{#2}}}
 \fallbackchar{ʤ}
 \fallbackchar{ʧ}

% Package for CJK fonts
\usepackage[fallback]{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimHei}
\setCJKfallbackfamilyfont{rm}{SimHei} 

\begin{document} 

Latin text and Bengali text \textbengali{নাম হাতটা কাছে দারাতে হবে} and Latin again. 

Latin text and Bengali text নাম হাতটা কাছে দারাতে হবে and Latin again. 

Some phonetic characters ʤ in yet another font ʧ. 

CJK example 漢字源

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at `ucharclasses`. I think it does what you want.

Comment: @JavierBezos This is indeed what I'm looking for!    However, I'm running into trouble.  It only works when there are spaces after unicode block transitions.  E.g., if there's a punctuation mark and then a space, after that space it still remains in the Bengali font.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm using With `\usepackage[Bengali]{ucharclasses}
\newfontfamily{\bengalifont}[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Bangla MN}
\setTransitionsFor{Bengali}{\bengalifont}{\rmfamily}`