CJK typesetting: how to list available fonts (linux)?
I'm trying to learn how to write Chinese in LaTeX (using TeXstudio on Debian Linux) - I've found this example, which works:
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{ctex} % 这里调用　ctex 包

%opening
\title{TITLE}
\author{MY NAME}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \paragraph{现在应该可以看到中文了}
\end{document}

I'd like to change the font to one that is less 'square', but I can't seem to find a way to list all the CJK fonts that are available to my environment; is there a straight forward way?
I have tried things like:
# fc-list  | grep CN | cut -d\  -f2-99 | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u
AR PL UMing CN

which, by the way, doesn't list all the Chinese fonts I have installed - and anyway, I don't know how to use that information. What should I do instead?
Edit
Trying albatross as suggested in the comments gives the following, very long list:
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Font name                                                                   │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ AR PL KaitiM GB,文鼎ＰＬ简中楷                                              │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ AR PL SungtiL GB,文鼎ＰＬ简报宋                                             │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ AR PL UKai CN                                                               │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ AR PL UKai HK                                                               │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ AR PL UKai TW                                                               │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ AR PL UKai TW MBE                                                           │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
...

The problem, then, seems to be that I don't know how to choose one of them in my LaTeX code; I've never actually had to change fonts or typefaces - most of my experience is from maths and using TikZ.
Maybe I just lack the necessary knowledge about these things - from what I find on google, it seems I need to find the Berry name, but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to do this (?)

Related (and IMHO useful but not really the same question): Standard CJK fonts for LaTeX?, What Chinese fonts can I rely on to be in Mac and Linux?

Can you read the cetex manual (in Chinese: I can't) ? https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/language/chinese/ctex/ctex.pdf // Does this topic on ctan help you? https://www.ctan.org/topic/chinese // Did you check the Related links to the right, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53599/standard-cjk-fonts-for-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1 ? // Did you click on your tag? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cjk

albatross 这  should list all the fonts you have that have that character

Expanding on David's comment: use albatross 這 for traditional Chinese, just in case you need it ...

fc-list :lang=zh?

@MS-SPO No, unfortunately I can't easily read the ctex manual; I'm still learning.
