# Vertical Chinese text that contains characters in a "CJK fallback family font"

Tags: xetex, rotating, cjk, xecjk

I am having trouble with vertical (i.e. rotated) Chinese text that contains characters in two different fonts. Rare characters requiring the "CJK fallback family font" are not displaying in the typeset output, although the font (PMingLiU-ExtB) is correctly installed and these characters do display in other applications, and even in LaTeX with the `xeCJK` package but without character-rotation. I've tried another font containing one of the characters in question, with the same result.

Here is a MWE, incorporating code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38585/3935 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16087/3935:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\newfontlanguage{Chinese}{CHN}
\setCJKmainfont[Script=CJK,Language=Chinese,Vertical=RotatedGlyphs]{SimSun}
\setCJKfallbackfamilyfont{rm}{PMingLiU-ExtB}

\newcommand*\CJKmovesymbol[1]{\raise.35em\hbox{#1}}
\newcommand*\CJKmove{\punctstyle{plain}% do not modify the spacing between punctuations
  \let\CJKsymbol\CJKmovesymbol
  \let\CJKpunctsymbol\CJKsymbol}

\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\CJKmove\special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate 90>>}}

\begin{document}
　　秋夜思

旅夢何時盡、征途望每賖、晩秋淮上水、新月楚人家

嘯空山近、鴻飛極浦斜、明朝南岸去、言折桂枝花
\end{document}
```

The character that produces the problem is  (U+24814), the first character in the third "paragraph" of the text.

I am using

```
revision:    28816
cat-version: 3.1.2
```

of `xeCJK` on OS 10.6.8 and 10.8.3; my LaTeX client is TeXShop v. 2.47.

If I change

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
```

to

```
\usepackage[fallback]{xeCJK}[2011/05/01] % ver 2.3.19
```

following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16087/3935, the character in question displays correctly but the text is no longer rotated. Is there a way to get both effects simultaneously?

---

**Added, 20130426**:

Using

```
\usepackage[AutoFallBack=true]{xeCJK}
\newfontlanguage{Chinese}{CHN}
\setCJKmainfont[Script=CJK,Language=Chinese,Vertical=RotatedGlyphs]{SimSun}
\setCJKfallbackfamilyfont{rm}[Script=CJK,Language=Chinese,Vertical=RotatedGlyphs]{MingLiU-ExtB}
```

as in @Leo Liu's answer produces overstriking of the graphs  and 嘯:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer `xeCJK` disables fallback fonts by default to improve the performence. So you should enable it manually.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[AutoFallBack=true]{xeCJK}
\newfontlanguage{Chinese}{CHN}
\setCJKmainfont[Script=CJK,Language=Chinese,Vertical=RotatedGlyphs]{SimSun}
\setCJKfallbackfamilyfont{rm}[Script=CJK,Language=Chinese,Vertical=RotatedGlyphs]{PMingLiU-ExtB}

\newcommand*\CJKmovesymbol[1]{\raise.35em\hbox{#1}}
\newcommand*\CJKmove{\punctstyle{plain}% do not modify the spacing between punctuations
  \let\CJKsymbol\CJKmovesymbol
  \let\CJKpunctsymbol\CJKsymbol}

\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\CJKmove\special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate 90>>}}

\begin{document}
　　秋夜思

旅夢何時盡、征途望每賖、晩秋淮上水、新月楚人家

嘯空山近、鴻飛極浦斜、明朝南岸去、言折桂枝花
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: However, this does not produce the desired effect — the characters  and 嘯 are overstruck, one on top of the other. I am appending a graphic to the original post.

Comment: @brannerchinese: It works fine on my computer.

Comment: @brannerchinese: I guess you use a bad `PMingLiU-ExtB` font. You can try another font like `SimSun-ExtB`, `HanaMin` (花園明朝), etc.

Comment: Yes, `SimSun-ExtB` works. I'm not sure what was wrong with `PMingLiU-ExtB`, but anyway I've got something that works now. Thanks.