# hyperref in bxjsarticle alters page dimensions and text area (TeXLive 2021)

Tags: hyperref, geometry, xecjk, flowfram

I find the presence of `hyperref` in a `bxjsarticle` document with `flowfram` causes effects in TeXLive 2021 that I did not see in TeXLive 2019. I'm hoping to find a workaround, to retain `hyperref` without fine adjustments to the geometry of the document.

My document is in 16x9 aspect ratio and uses CJK characters typeset in vertical columns, right to left.

With `hyperref` present, I don't seem to be able to control the aspect ratio using `geometry`; in addition, the text area shift well to the right.

Vertical Chinese handling is based on [For vertical CJK in XeLaTex, how can I have roman characters aligned with chinese characters, and have chinese fonts "fallback" properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401925/for-vertical-cjk-in-xelatex-how-can-i-have-roman-characters-aligned-with-chines) (from 2017). I am also using other effects described in that post, but the `hyperref` issue doesn't seem to affect those, so I have excluded them from my MWE.

---

MWE without `hyperref`. Works as expected:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[landscape,11pt,a4paper]{bxjsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{paperwidth=198 mm, paperheight=352 mm}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text,RawFeature={vertical}]{SimSun}

% Settings for a 90-degree rotated "flowframe" to enable vertical typesetting
\usepackage{flowfram}
\newflowframe%
 {\textheight}%
 {\textwidth+5em}%
 {0pt}%
 {\textheight}[mainframe] 
\setflowframe{1}{angle=-90} 

\begin{document}

\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont
\raggedright

\vspace*{\fill}

一行中僅排漢字十為止

\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

[image: Without hyperref, page dimensions and text area are as expected.]

---

MWE with `hyperref` present; both page dimensions and text area are altered shifted drastically:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[landscape,11pt,a4paper]{bxjsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{paperwidth=198 mm, paperheight=352 mm}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text,RawFeature={vertical}]{SimSun}

% Settings for a 90-degree rotated "flowframe" to enable vertical typesetting
\usepackage{flowfram}
\newflowframe%
 {\textheight}%
 {\textwidth+5em}%
 {0pt}%
 {\textheight}[mainframe] 
\setflowframe{1}{angle=-90} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont
\raggedright

\vspace*{\fill}

一行中僅排漢字十為止

\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hyperref alters page dimensions and text area.]

Comment: well I don't think that I want to understand what this class is doing regarding geometry settings. It seems to confuse hyperref quite thoroughly. You can use `\usepackage[setpagesize=false]{hyperref}`, then hyperref will leave the page size alone and the class and geometry can fight it out.

Comment: That does indeed to resolve everything instantly. Many thanks!