# Overstriking CJK characters with traditional Chinese tone marks, in xeCJK

Tags: vertical, xecjk

Unicode includes twelve special symbols used for indicating tones on CJK characters. Four are traditional in Chinese civilization itself: U+302A: `〪` ("ideographic level tone mark") through U+302D. Another eight were introduced in the mid-nineteenth century by Western missionaries and have been taken up within native Chinese philology: U+A700: `꜀` "modifier letter Chinese tone yin ping" through U+A707.

I am wondering if there is a standard way to use these to overstrike CJK characters in xeCJK. (An additional complication is that I am typesetting vertical text, using the built-in xeCJK option for that.)

---

In the minimal working examples below, I've attempted to mark two occurrences of 遺 with the "level" and "departing" tone marks. The marks appear, but not where they're supposed to.

Vertical text for Chinese with this package is supported chiefly by the Simsun font, which doesn't contain the various tone-mark characters. So I have created new CJK font families in order to load fonts that have the characters in question. But those fonts don't support the `RawFeature={vertical}` option of `xeCJK`, and that may be part of what's going wrong.

I had hoped perhaps `xeCJK` might have a built-in tool for marking characters with these traditional marks.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{bxjsarticle}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text,RawFeature={vertical}]{SimSun}

% To get traditional tone marks for ``ideographic tone mark'' (ITM) characters
\newCJKfontfamily\ITMtones{BabelStone Han}
\newCJKfontfamily\ITMtonesA{HAN NOM A}
\newCJKfontfamily\ITMtonesB{Hanazono Mincho A Regular}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont

BabelStone Han:\vskip1em

誠宜開張聖聽、以光先帝{\ITMtones{〪}}遺德、恢弘志士之氣、不宜妄自菲薄、\dots 是以先帝簡拔以遺{\ITMtones{  〬}}陛下、愚以為、宮中之事、事無大小、悉以咨之\dots 

\clearpage

HAN NOM A:\vskip1em

誠宜開張聖聽、以光先帝{\ITMtonesA{〪}}遺德、恢弘志士之氣、不宜妄自菲薄、\dots 是以先帝簡拔以遺{\ITMtonesA{  〬}}陛下、愚以為、宮中之事、事無大小、悉以咨之\dots

\clearpage

Hanazono Mincho A Regular:\vskip1em

誠宜開張聖聽、以光先帝{\ITMtonesB{〪}}遺德、恢弘志士之氣、不宜妄自菲薄、\dots 是以先帝簡拔以遺{\ITMtonesB{  〬}}陛下、愚以為、宮中之事、事無大小、悉以咨之\dots

\end{document}
```

---

[image: BabelStone Han example]

---

[image: HAN NOM A example]

---

[image: Hanazono Mincho A Regular example]

Comment: It would help if you provided an example, does it not work if you simply follow a character by `〪` ?

Comment: You will need a font with vertical feature, the glyphs, and the rules for attaching the tone marks. `Microsoft JhengHei` has the first two, but not the rules. `Code2003` has the first two and the rules for horizontal mode but not vertical. I would expect a Japanese font to be unlikely to have Chinese tone mark rules (it may). Unrelated - the font switches do not take arguments. Not unrelated - using grouping with `{...}` will break the font's positioning rules if it has any (glyphs have anchor points, and the {} between glyphs will hide that).

Comment: Having said that, the `tikz` package could be used to "manually" position the marks. Alternatively, kerning with `\kern...` command, and use of `\raisebox`, is an option.

Comment: @Cicada: If I don't use the outer curly brackets of `{\ITMtones{〪}}`, the vertical functionality breaks. If I don't use the inner ones, TeX then thinks the tone mark is part of the name of the `\ITMtones` command, and it won't compile. So I guess that's why you're saying all three features must be present in the same font.

Comment: @Cicada: I will look into `tikz`, `stackengine` and `\kern`. But in my experience, highly tuned adjustments of this kind sometimes break when LaTeX versions change, and when there are other complexities (such as rotating the page, adjusting the font size of Western-language text, and so on — things not in the MWE).

Comment: If I'm going to do overstriking manually, then I don't need to stick with the existing Unicode symbols for these marks. Probably the simplest thing would be to use a plain Roman letter `o`. In traditional times, these marks consisted simply of a circle or a brush-tip-shaped dollop of ink. (The traditional punctuation mark 、 has the same origin, although it was placed outside the form of the character it applied to, rather than on top of it.)

Comment: Not an answer: the [xpinyin](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpinyin), [hanzibox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hanzibox), [kanbun](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/kanbun), [gckanbun](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gckanbun), and [luatexja-ruby](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/luatex/generic/luatexja/doc/luatexja-ruby.pdf) packages all, in some form, place marks/text around Chinese characters and work in vertical typesetting. Perhaps looking through their code could be illuminating

Answer (score 1):

Not very good, but a quick and dirty solution using `\kern` and `\raisebox`, both tuned manually. In order to avoid font issues, I am using the Roman letter `o` for the traditional tone-mark circle, instead of the prescribed Unicode characters.

Doing it this way introduces infelicities in both leading and kerning, which I have also tuned manually. The result is still imperfect — among other things, the first line is one character shorter than the rest of the paragraph. I'd be grateful to hear of better solutions.

[In addition to 遺, I have marked both 菲 and 不 here, as they each have alternate *píngshēng* readings in the philological sources. Here we want their *shǎngshēng* and *rùshēng* readings, respectively.]

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{bxjsarticle}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text,RawFeature={vertical}]{SimSun}
\usepackage{setspace}  % Provides \setstretch

% To get overstruck ``o'' to represent traditional corner tone marks
% píngshēng 平聲: overstruck circle at lower left corner of character
\newcommand\pyng[1]{#1\kern-14pt{%
 \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\textbf{\raisebox{-1.6ex}o}}%
\kern2pt}

% shǎngshēng 上聲: overstruck circle at upper left corner of character
\newcommand\shaang[1]{#1\kern-40pt{%
 \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\textbf{\raisebox{-1.6ex}o}}%
\kern27pt}

% qùshēng 去聲: overstruck circle at upper right corner of character
\newcommand\chiuh[1]{#1\kern-40pt{%
 \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\textbf{\raisebox{0.6ex}o}}%
\kern27pt}

% rùshēng 入聲: overstruck circle at lower right corner of character
\newcommand\ruh[1]{#1\kern-14pt{%
 \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\textbf{\raisebox{0.6ex}o}}{}%
\kern2pt}

\begin{document}

\raggedright      % Reduce kerning distortion (default justified alignment is worse).
\setstretch{1.25} % Reduce leading distortion.

\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont

Using \texttt{\textbackslash kern} and \texttt{\textbackslash raisebox}, hand-tuned:

誠宜開張聖聽、以光先帝\pyng{遺}德、恢弘志士之氣、\ruh{不}宜妄自\shaang{菲}薄、…是以先帝簡拔以\chiuh{遺}陛下、愚以為、宮中之事、事無大小、悉以咨之…

\end{document}
```

[image: using \kern and \raisebox, hand-tuned]

---

With all the other bells and whistles I am using to get the full rotated text and adjusted punctuation marks, the result is tolerable:

[image]

I'll put the full code in, for reference by interested hands — I'd still be grateful to see a more elegant solution.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{bxjsarticle}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text,RawFeature={vertical}]{SimSun}
\setCJKfallbackfamilyfont{rm}[Script=CJK,RawFeature={vertical}]{SimSun-ExtB}
% To get IPA font, set as nominally \texttt
\setmonofont[Scale=1,Mapping=tex-text]{Doulos SIL}
% The following adjustments improve kerning.
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{。}{\hspace{0pt}。\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{，}{\hspace{0pt}，\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{﹐}{\hspace{0pt}﹐\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{︐}{\hspace{0pt}︐\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{；}{\hspace{0pt}；\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{：}{\hspace{0pt}：\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{、}{\hspace{0pt}、\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{！}{\hspace{0pt}！\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{？}{\hspace{0pt}？\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{（}{\hspace{0pt}（\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{）}{\hspace{0pt}）\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{《}{\hspace{0pt}《\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{》}{\hspace{0pt}》\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{「}{\hspace{0pt}「\hspace{0pt}}
\newunicodechar{」}{\hspace{0pt}」\hspace{0pt}}

\usepackage{xeCJKfntef} % enable \CJKunderline etc.

\usepackage{setspace}  % enable \setstretch

% Settings for a 90-degree rotated "flowframe" to enable vertical typesetting
% (Following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402025/3935)
\usepackage{flowfram}
\newflowframe{\textheight}{\textwidth+2em}{0pt}{\textheight}[mainframe] 
\setflowframe{1}{angle=-90} 

% Command to properly align roman characters with Chinese characters:
% (Following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402025/3935)
\let\CJKsymbolOrig\CJKsymbol
\let\CJKpunctsymbolOrig\CJKpunctsymbol
\newcommand*\CJKmovesymbol[1]{\raise.35em\hbox{\CJKsymbolOrig{#1}}}
\newcommand*\CJKmovepunctsymbol[1]{\raise.35em\hbox{\CJKpunctsymbolOrig{#1}}}
\newcommand*\CJKmove{\punctstyle{plain}
  \let\CJKsymbol\CJKmovesymbol
  \let\CJKpunctsymbol\CJKmovepunctsymbol
}

% To get overstruck ``o'' to represent the four traditional corner tone marks
% píngshēng 平聲: overstruck circle at lower left corner of character
\newcommand\pyng[1]{#1\kern-14pt{%
 \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\textbf{\raisebox{-.4ex}o}}}%
%\kern2pt}

% shǎngshēng 上聲: overstruck circle at upper left corner of character
\newcommand\shaang[1]{#1\kern-40pt{%
 \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\textbf{\raisebox{-.4ex}o}}%
\kern27pt}

% qùshēng 去聲: overstruck circle at upper right corner of character
\newcommand\chiuh[1]{#1\kern-40pt{%
 \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\textbf{\raisebox{1.9ex}o}}%
\kern27pt}

% rùshēng 入聲: overstruck circle at lower right corner of character
\newcommand\ruh[1]{#1\kern-14pt{%
 \fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont\textbf{\raisebox{1.9ex}o}}}%
%\kern2pt}

\begin{document}
\CJKmove % Adjusts positioning of Roman font vis-à-vis CJK, and also CJK punctuation

\raggedright        % Makes parskip unnecessary here, more neatly.
\setstretch{1.25} % Reduce leading distortion.

\vspace*{\fill}

\pagenumbering{gobble}          % No page-numbering starting here

\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont

誠宜開張聖聽、以光先帝\pyng{遺}德、恢弘志士之氣、\ruh{不}宜妄自\shaang{菲}薄、…是以先帝簡拔以\chiuh{遺}陛下、愚以為、宮中之事、事無大小、悉以咨之…

\vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `Noto Sans CJK TC` font is perfect, except for being sans. `Noto Serif CJK TC` caters for horizontal marks only.

Comment: @Cicada: That's interesting to know. How is coverage of rare graphs in Noto Sans CJK TC? Simsun requires the Extension B annex as fallback, and the usually excellent HanaMin font requires a whole bunch of extensions. I now use Babelstone Han in my regular Western-language publications, but it doesn't seem to support vertical text, alas.

Comment: Font coverage: Simsun 28737; Microsoft JhengHei 29593; Noto Serif CJK TC 43029; Noto Sans CJK TC 44683. For Noto (from Google), derivation is the free Source Han fonts, at [GitHub](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif/releases). Any examples of rare glyphs? I don't know the field.

Comment: @Cicada: Graphs at or above U+20000 (plane CJK Unified Ideographs Ext. B/C/D/E/F etc.) generally represent rarely seen glyphs. Some are exquisitely outré:  (U+2D588),  (U+2D6A5),  (U+2B6CA),  (U+2ABE1), etc.