# Error while printing chinese character

Tags: errors, unicode, cjk

I am printing a document with Chinese and getting some errors. Below is a MWE with the character causing problems.

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
 塞
\end{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
\end{document}
```

This is the error message:

```
Error:
! Font C70/gbsn/m/n/10.95/f9=gbsnuf9 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file
 not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

For Chinese, you can read this first:

[How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex)

The CJK symbol `塞`(U+F96C) you want to typeset is “CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH”.
It is rarely used for Chinese or Japanese documents, but for Korean. So most Chinese fonts (including `gbsn` installed on TeX distributions) do not have this symbol.

I don't know what you want actually. If you just want to typeset `塞`(U+585E), it is OK to use:

```
% pdflatex or latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
塞 for Chinese
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

But if you really need `塞`(U+F96C) for Korean, you have to use a proper font for this symbol. Say, use a Korean font

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{mj}
塞 for Korean
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

You can also use XeLaTeX and a font from your OS. On Windows, for example,

```
% xelatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Batang}
\begin{document}
塞 VS. 塞
\end{document}
```

---

BTW, this might be helpful if you need to typeset rare symbols:

[high and low CJK codepoints in a single XeLaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16084/high-and-low-cjk-codepoints-in-a-single-xelatex-document/)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create Chinese pdf, perhaps you can try the package xeCJK. I suggest the following article for you:

http://leavedcorn.pixnet.net/blog/post/24773932-%E6%96%B0%E6%89%8B%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%9Dlatex%E6%87%B6%E4%BA%BA%E6%95%99%E5%AD%B8(step-by-step)

Comment: In order to make this a more complete answer (right now it’s more of a comment), could you show  how th OP’s character would be produced in a xeCJK minimal?

Comment: Can u use xeCJK with pdflatex. I m using pdflatex so i don't want to use xetex.

Comment: @user15662: You can't use `xeCJK` with pdflatex.